# how to redirect to another .jsf page from fragment on button click

Tags: oracle-adf, weblogic12c, jdeveloper, oracle-fusion-middleware

I am using fragments in my application.
There are 2 jsf pages abc.jsf and xyz.jsf.
In abc.jsf page there is a fragment of name jkl.jsff is showing, in that fragment there is a button through which i want to redirect to xyz.jsf page.
How i can redirect from fragment to another .jsf page?

Comment: You could just add a navigation rule in the taskflow which contains the two .jsf pages, then bind that action to any button

Answer (score 1):

In the abc.jsf Taskflow add **Parent Action** and set the value **Parent Outcome** property as it is between abc.jsf and xyz.jsf